# Why does exclamation marks create linebreaks in the Index of first lines? (Poetry package)

Tags: makeindex, poetry

I'm using the Poetry package to create an anthology of poems. The package provides an automatic creation of an Index of First Lines, which works well -- except, it turns out, when the first line includes an exclamation mark. This creates a line break in the index (although not in the type-setting of the poem itself).

I think the problem lies in ! being used for MakeIndex, but similar problems seem to be solved by adding a " in front of the !. This doesn't seem to work in this case (and also includes the quotation mark in the type-set text, which of course isn't what I'd want).

The documentation for the poetry package can be found at https://ctan.org/pkg/poetry

Minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{poetry}\poemlinenumsfalse

\begin{document}
\subsection*{The man from Nantucket}
\begin{poem}
\iofl{There once was a man from Nantucket}\\
Who kept all his cash in a bucket\\
Has daughter, named Nan\\
Ran away with a man\\
And as for the bucket, Nan tuck'it\\-
\end{poem}

\subsection*{Clementine}
\begin{poem}
\iofl{In a canyon}\\
In a cavern\\
Excavating from a mine\\
Lived a miner,\\
Forty-niner\\
And his daughter, Clementine\\-
\end{poem}


\subsection*{Marvin's lullaby}
\begin{poem}
\iofl{Now the world! has gone to bed},\\
Darkness won't engulf my head,\\
I can see by infrared,\\
How I hate the night.\\!

Now I lay me down to sleep,\\
Try to count electric sheep,\\
Sweet dream wishes you can keep,\\
How I hate the night.\\-
\end{poem}

\printiofl

\end{document}
```

There's another way of adding lined to the index, but it produces the same result.

I'm grateful for all help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`!` is by default a special character for makeindex to separate nested entries.

So you can use `\poemfirsline` and enter the index entry with `!` quoted as `"!`  or you could use a custom index style

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{poetry}\poemlinenumsfalse

\begin{document}
\subsection*{The man from Nantucket}
\begin{poem}
\iofl{There once was a man from Nantucket}\\
Who kept all his cash in a bucket\\
Has daughter, named Nan\\
Ran away with a man\\
And as for the bucket, Nan tuck'it\\-
\end{poem}

\subsection*{Clementine}
\begin{poem}
\iofl{In a canyon}\\
In a cavern\\
Excavating from a mine\\
Lived a miner,\\
Forty-niner\\
And his daughter, Clementine\\-
\end{poem}


\subsection*{Marvin's lullaby}
\begin{poem}
\poemfirstline{Now the world"! has gone to bed}
Now the world! has gone to bed,\\
Darkness won't engulf my head,\\
I can see by infrared,\\
How I hate the night.\\!

Now I lay me down to sleep,\\
Try to count electric sheep,\\
Sweet dream wishes you can keep,\\
How I hate the night.\\-
\end{poem}

\printiofl

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! I did try escaping with ", but it didn't work. Copying your code did work however -- turns out TeXworks changes a straight quotation mark to two apostrophes and I didn't see the difference...